# How to force eager load at runtime?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I'm using Fluent NHibernate. I have an object at runtime with lazy collections/properties that may or may not have been populated. I plan on serializing that object and need all the collections/properties to be populated before I do so. How can I "eager-load" my object at runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have the relationships set in you mappings you do not need to specify how to join in your query, you could simply use Fetch (even deep fetch) to specify the path to be loaded eaderly:

```
session.QueryOver<MasterEnt>()
   .Where(x => x.Id == 2)
   .Fetch(x => x.DetailEntList)
   .Eager().List();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ICriteria` and manipulate the load through `NHibernate.ICriteria.SetFetchMode(string, NHibernate.FetchMode)`.

Example:

DetailEnt.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace FetchTest
{
    public class DetailEnt
    {
        private Int32? id;
        /// <summary>
        /// Entity key
        /// </summary>
        public virtual Int32? Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        private String description;
        /// <summary>
        /// Description
        /// </summary>
        public virtual String Description
        {
            get { return description; }
            set { description = value; }
        }

        private MasterEnt rIMaster;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the RI master.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The RI master.
        /// </value>
        public virtual MasterEnt RIMaster
        {
            get { return rIMaster; }
            set { rIMaster = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

MasterEnt.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace FetchTest
{
    public class MasterEnt
    {
        private Int32? id;
        /// <summary>
        /// Entity key
        /// </summary>
        public virtual Int32? Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        private String description;
        /// <summary>
        /// Description
        /// </summary>
        public virtual String Description
        {
            get { return description; }
            set { description = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<DetailEnt> detailEntList;
        /// <summary>
        /// <see cref="RIDetailEnt"/> one-to-many relationship.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual ICollection<DetailEnt> DetailEntList
        {
            get { return detailEntList; }
            set { detailEntList = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Forcing eager load at runtime:

```
NHibernate.ISession ss = GetSessionFromSomeWhere();

NHibernate.ICriteria crt = ss.CreateCriteria<MasterEnt>();
crt
    .Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Expression.IdEq(17))
    //here is "force eager load at runtime"
    .SetFetchMode("DetailEntList", NHibernate.FetchMode.Join);
MasterEnt mEnt = crt.UniqueResult<MasterEnt>();
```

In this case I used "hbm". But the logic should be the same.

### EDITED:

With "NHibernate 2.1.2" and "NHibernate.Linq"

```
INHibernateQueryable<MasterEnt> nhq = null;
IList<MasterEnt> masterList = null;

nhq = (INHibernateQueryable<MasterEnt>)(
    from master in session.Linq<MasterEnt>()
    where master.Id == 2
    select master);

nhq.Expand("DetailEntList");
masterList = nhq.ToList<MasterEnt>();
```

with `QueryOver<T>Left.JoinQueryOver` from NHibernate 3:

```
IQueryOver<MasterEnt> query = session.QueryOver<MasterEnt>()
    .Left.JoinQueryOver<DetailEnt>(m => m.DetailEntList)
    .Where(m => m.Id == 2);

masterList = query.List<MasterEnt>();
```

These queries work this way independently if using "FluentNHibernate" or "hbm".

I made some code for it, soon I'll post the links to the files.

### EDITED 2:

I've posted the code on [q_10303345_1350308.7z](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49510149/stackoverflow/dotnet/q_10303345_1350308.7z) (runnable by NUnit). There are explanations about the dependencies in the "dependencies \ readme.txt". The dll dependencies are loaded by NuGet.